# memory leak with either array or CGImageRef

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I am making a program that strips out frames from a movie. This in Simulator of Xcode 5.0 on iOS 7. The number of objects I am trying to put in this array are 447. (Doesn't seem that many).

My program continuously crashes due to a memory leak either due to array size not being large enough?? (no idea if this statement is right) or due to something else. It consistently fails in the for loop only for vidoes whose number of frames are greater than 350. Less frame videos work fine.

Just a hunch could it have anything to do with the fact that I am storing large original frame  images into an array? I am not scaling the frame pics down?

```
CODE:
NSMutableArray* allFrames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    // get each frame
    for (int k=0; k< totalFrames; k++)
    {

        int timeValue = timeValuePerFrame * k;
        CMTime frameTime;
        frameTime.value = timeValue;
        frameTime.timescale = movie.duration.timescale;
        frameTime.flags = movie.duration.flags;
        frameTime.epoch = movie.duration.epoch;

        CMTime gotTime;

        CGImageRef myRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:frameTime actualTime:&gotTime error:nil];
        [allFrames addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:myRef]];

        if (gotTime.value != frameTime.value)
            NSLog (@"requested %lld got %lld for k %d", frameTime.value, gotTime.value, k);

        //cleanup?
        CFRelease(myRef);



    }

    ERROR:
2013-11-03 20:18:24.746 test[42139:a0b] requested 9925 got 9921 for k 397
2013-11-03 20:18:25.122 test[42139:a0b] requested 9950 got 9946 for k 398
    everseHD(42046,0xb029b000) malloc: *** mmap(size=8298496) failed (error code=12)
    *** error: can't allocate region
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    2013-11-03 20:10:31.936 ReverseHD[42046:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x020305e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01db38b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x01fe2c3c -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 844
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x01fe28e0 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 64
        4   ReverseHD                           0x00003131 -[v1ViewController extractImagesFromMovie] + 3089
        5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01dc5874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
        6   UIKit                               0x00b27c8c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
        7   UIKit                               0x00b27c18 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
        8   UIKit                               0x00c1f6d9 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
        9   UIKit                               0x00c1fa9c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
        10  UIKit                               0x00c1e815 -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 254
        11  UIKit                               0x00b64efb -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 386
        12  UIKit                               0x00b65d34 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
        13  UIKit                               0x00b39a36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
        14  UIKit                               0x00b23d9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x01fb98af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x01fb923b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x01fd630e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x01fd5b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x01fd594b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        20  GraphicsServices                    0x032239d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
        21  GraphicsServices                    0x032237fe GSEventRun + 104
        22  UIKit                               0x00b2694b UIApplicationMain + 1225
        23  ReverseHD                           0x0000244d main + 141
        24  libdyld.dylib                       0x02975725 start + 0
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: It's probably not the issue but you should use `CGImageRelease` as it's safer, since it checks for `NULL`.

Comment: It looks like Gabriel already helped you out with exactly what you need, but just as an aside, you can see from the failure message that your code attempts to allocate just under 8MiB for a single frame for the uncompressed image data. Multiply that by 447 frames, and you're talking about allocating almost 3.5 GiB of memory, which is not a small amount ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory leak **⇒** lots of memory used

Lots of memory used **⇏** memory leak

You are correctly releasing `myRef`, which you own since it was created with a `copy` method, so the code you posted doesn't present any leak.

You are just using a lot of memory by trying to store 447 images.

> Doesn't seem that many

is not a good evaluation. You should profile the application using Instruments with the Memory Allocation template and check for the size of the array, which is probably filling all the heap.

If you find out that the frames are too big to be stored in the array, you can reduce the size of the generated frame by using the `maximumSize` property of `AVAssetImageGenerator`, for instance

```
generator.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
```

As stated in the documentation:

> The default value is CGSizeZero, which specifies the asset’s unscaled dimensions.

Comment: Should I resize the image down to 50% and then store it in my array. Do you think that will help?

Comment: definitely, but you should diagnosticate the issue probably before. It could be something else.

Comment: ok, by the way do you know how a CGImageRef can be reduced down to 50%? Code wise i mean

Comment: Check my updated answer: you can directly generate a smaller frame

Comment: Wow, that was a simple one liner. I will try that.

Comment: You were absolutely right. My array was getting bloated with large images and was casusing this crash. Lowering the CGImageRef with generator made it work. Thanks dude.